# 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 = 0 and 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 = 0

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

There are many number sequence puzzles on this site. I acknowledge them all.

Martin Gardner introduced the puzzle with the 9 digit sequence with math operations, reaching 100 as below

> An old numerical problem that keeps reappearing in puzzle books as
>
> though it had never been analyzed before is the problem of inserting
>   mathematical signs wherever one likes between the digits 1, 2, 3, 4,
>   5, 6, 7, 8, 9 to make the expression equal 100. The digits must remain
>   in the same sequence. There are many hundreds of solutions, the
>   easiest to find perhaps being "
>
> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + ( 8 x 9 ) = 100

With concatenation allowed the fewest possible operations to get to 100 is

> 123-45-67+89=100 which uses only 3 operations

Based on that

> Using 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 and fewest math operations (4 or less), with parentheses counting as operations, can you get 0?
>
> AND do the same for Reverse order
>
> 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 = 0

Your answers must represent all the digits in sequence. All digits must appear once. Only + - x / !  allowed. Parentheses are counted as though they were operations; each pair of parentheses is 2 operations. Every sign introduced is a step. No partial answers. I expect more than one solutions. I have 4 step solutions but there may be 3 step solutions too.

Hope the moderators will not consider this as an open question

Comment: can we use a computer to solve this puzzle?

Comment: You can but I found it much more fun to do this on paper. There are logical deductions.

Comment: Is $(1)$ consider as two operations (two parenthesis) or is it only one since you need a right parenthesis for every left one? If it is the later, there is an easy 4 steps solution.

Comment: Does (x+y)z count as 2 or 3? Given the * is implied in standard notation

Comment: (1) will be 2 operations

Comment: (x+y)z will be 4 operations. You have introduces 4 signs ( + ) *

Comment: @DEEM thanks for clarifying. It mean a 3 step solution can't have parenthesis.

Comment: I read the puzzle and came up with a solution, only to read further and find out that parentheses are counted as though they were operations; whoops. I hope you don't mind if I submit an edit request which states in the main body that parentheses count as operations.

Comment: $1^{234567}+8-9=0$ - I'm not sure if this is allowed.

Comment: Very clever ThomasL but ^ was not included as part of the puzzle. But kudos for a 3 step solution for forward sequence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With 4 symbols.

For the normal sequence:

> 1*23-45-67+89

For the reverse sequence:

> 98-76-54+32*1

Answer (score 4):

This should be all solutions with 4 operations.
For the forward sequence:

> $$ 1*23 - 45 - 67 + 89 = 0 $$

For the backward sequence:

> $$  987 - 6! + 54 - 321=0\\98*7 - 654 - 32/1 = 0\\ 98*7 - 654 - 32*1 = 0\\  98 - 76 - 54 + 32/1 = 0\\ 98 - 76 - 54 + 32*1 = 0$$

The first three variations are not in any of the other answers :)

There is another variant for the forward sequence with factorial (5 steps)

> $$1 + 23 + 45 + 6! - 789 = 0$$

Comment: Good job on the backward sequence @daw. Is there a 3 step solution?

Comment: @DEEM Found another with factorial. But no 3 step solution

Answer (score 3):

A way to do it with $\color{red}{4}$ steps, considering parenthesis comes in pair (one step for the pair)

OP clarified that each individual parenthesis count so $5$ steps.

> $$(1+2-3)*456789=0$$
> $$987654*(3-2-1)=0$$

---

**Not part of the solution**, since the floor function is not allowed, but it could be done in $3$ step. Where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer smaller than $x$, e.g. $\lfloor 0.1\rfloor=0$.

> $$\lfloor1\div23456789\rfloor=0$$
> $$\lfloor9\div87654321\rfloor=0$$

Answer (score 2):

5 operations

> $(1+2-3) * 456789 = 0$ 
>  $987654 * (3-2-1) = 0$

4 operations

> $98-76-54+32*1$

Answer (score 1):

Using 5 operations:

> $(12/3-4)*56789=0$

Using 4 operations:

> $9 8- 7 6 -5 4+3 2/1 = 0$